# How do I disable user account in apacheDs

Tags: spring-security, spring-ldap, apacheds

I am using **ApacheDS 2.0.0.v20130628**,I use Spring security ldap to authenticate users.
For a new user,once user registers an account with the web application an email will be sent to make the account active so that his email will also be verified.Until User clicks on the link sent to his email,User should not be able to Login to the application.So how can I disable the user account till then?

I came across with an attribute on web **nsAccountLock**,But I am unable to find this attribute in ApacheDS.

I want to know is there anything in **ldap-user-service** like "active" which is used in a SQL query for **JDBC User service** in spring security?

Any suggestions as how to go about on this?

Answer (score 0):

**nsAccountLock** is used to lock accounts in **Oracle Directory Server**. But not in apache Directory server. even i'm facing the same issue for finding attribute for disabling user in Apache DS. its looks like they havent created any attribute for it.

Comment: any Success on this?

Answer (score 0):

I have used 'pager' as a option to know if the user is enabled or disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'pwdAccountLockedTime' operationsl attribute, that's the standard way in Apache DS.

For more details [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32348831/how-to-unlock-user-on-apacheds)